# Something like a resizeable WrapPannel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wrappanel

I am looking for a wrappanel or rather something that works similarly. The wrappanel grabs the Uielement in a new line, but the elements are not dynamic in width, but static. The setting »HorizontalAlignment=" Stretch"« does not work and the elements look squeezed together. That means you have to put the width manually »Width="200"« and that is very static. So when I change the width of my window, more elements come into one line, but the existing elements do not adapt to the width of the window. I would have liked to fill out the elements for the entire width. Overall, it also sees much better.

I made a user control that fits my purpose but it can’t be virtualized and is really slow with the resize.
Here is my code for the adaptable UserControl.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="ItemViewer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450"
             d:DesignWidth="800"
             Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
             x:Name="uc">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=uc}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"
                           x:Name="SecondRow" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Header"
                   Text="{Binding HeaderText,Mode=OneWay}"
                   Foreground="White"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="0,0,0,10"
                   FontSize="28"
                   FontWeight="Medium" />

        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2"
                      x:Name="ListViewProducts"
                      SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items,Mode=OneWay}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid   Height="{Binding Path=DataContext.ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl},Mode=OneTime}"
                            MaxWidth="{Binding Path=DataContext.ItemMaxWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl},Mode=OneTime}"
                            Margin="0,0,10,10">

                        <Border Background="Beige"
                                CornerRadius="10" />
                     <!-- The specific UserControl or an element -->
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="2"
                                 Initialized="UniformGrid_Initialized" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                            Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                            Value="Top" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code behind:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace MVVM.View.HomeView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für ItemViewer.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ItemViewer : UserControl
    {
        private UniformGrid? _itemUniformGrid;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(HeaderText), typeof(string), typeof(ItemViewer));
        public string HeaderText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemHeight", typeof(double), typeof(ItemViewer));
        public double ItemHeight
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ItemHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemHeightProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemMinWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemMinWidth", typeof(double), typeof(ItemViewer));
        public double ItemMinWidth { get { return (double)GetValue(ItemMinWidthProperty); } set { SetValue(ItemMinWidthProperty, value); List_SizeChanged(); } }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemWidth", typeof(double), typeof(ItemViewer));
        public double ItemWidth { get { return (double)GetValue(ItemWidthProperty); } set { SetValue(ItemWidthProperty, value); List_SizeChanged(); } }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemMaxWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemMaxWidth", typeof(double), typeof(ItemViewer));
        public double ItemMaxWidth { get { return (double)GetValue(ItemMaxWidthProperty); } set { SetValue(ItemMaxWidthProperty, value); List_SizeChanged(); } }

        private double row = 0;
        public double Row { get { return row; } set { row = (value >= 0 ? value : 0); if (Row != 0) { SecondRow.MaxHeight = 10 * (Row - 1) + ItemHeight * Row; } } }

        public ItemViewer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int itemCounter = 0;

        public ObservableCollection<object> Items
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
            set => SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);

        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(ItemViewer));

        private const int WmExitSizeMove = 0x232;
        private IntPtr HwndMessageHook(IntPtr wnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            switch (msg)
            {
                case WmExitSizeMove:
                    List_SizeChanged();
                    handled = true;
                    break;
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        private void List_SizeChanged()
        {
            if (Items == null || Items.Count == 0 || _itemUniformGrid == null)
                return;

            itemCounter = Items.Count;

            int columns = (int)(ListViewProducts.ActualWidth / (10 + ItemWidth));
            if (columns <= itemCounter && ListViewProducts.ActualWidth < (ItemMaxWidth + 10) * columns)
            {

                if (_itemUniformGrid.HorizontalAlignment != HorizontalAlignment.Stretch)
                {
                    _itemUniformGrid.ClearValue(WidthProperty);
                    _itemUniformGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                }
                if (columns != _itemUniformGrid.Columns)
                    _itemUniformGrid.Columns = columns;
            }
            else
            {
                if (columns >= itemCounter)
                {
                    double newWidth;
                    newWidth = ListViewProducts.ActualWidth / itemCounter;
                    newWidth = newWidth > ItemMaxWidth ? ItemMaxWidth : newWidth;
                    _itemUniformGrid.Width = (newWidth + 10) * itemCounter;
                    _itemUniformGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    _itemUniformGrid.Columns = itemCounter;
                }
                else
                {
                    _itemUniformGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    _itemUniformGrid.Columns = (int)(ListViewProducts.ActualWidth / (ItemMaxWidth + 10));
                    _itemUniformGrid.Width = (ItemMaxWidth + 10) * _itemUniformGrid.Columns;
                }
            }
        }

        private void UniformGrid_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
                _itemUniformGrid = (UniformGrid)sender;

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List_SizeChanged();
            if (Application.Current.MainWindow == null)
                return;
            WindowInteropHelper? helper = new(Application.Current.MainWindow);

            HwndSource? source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(helper.Handle);
            if (source != null)
                source.AddHook(HwndMessageHook);
        }

        private int sizeP = 0;
        private void Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (sizeP - e.NewSize.Width is < (-200) or > 200)
            {
                sizeP = (int)e.NewSize.Width;
                List_SizeChanged();
            }
            else if (Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized && sizeP != (int)e.NewSize.Width)
            {
                sizeP = (int)e.NewSize.Width;
                List_SizeChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```xml
<local:ItemViewer Items="{Binding Objects}"
                              HeaderText="Recent"
                              ItemMinWidth="200"
                              ItemWidth="350"
                              ItemHeight="150"
                              ItemMaxWidth="500"
                              Row="1" />
```

To make it more responsive I call the resized only when the resize finished. I think it doesn't break with mvvm because it is only for the UI. But in the end, it is quite a bad implementation.
So, is there a better way or good code on GitHub that has a similar behaviour? Here are a few Images of an implementation of my code:
The Width is set dynamically and it wraps when there is enough space.

Here my implementation of my UserControl. The Broders have a dynamic width and also can wrap, but is realy slow.
[image: GifWindow]
Here the same with a WrapPanel. Static width and fast wrapping
[image: GifWindow]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Are you trying to dynamically control the number of columns based on the control width?

Comment: No, I would like to have a Control that has similar function. So that the item can scale with auto width but if the size of the View is big enough is wraps another item is shown. I solved it with a UniformGrid where I Control the columns manually to get this behaviour.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still just don't get it. "So that the item can scale with auto width but if the size of the View is big enough is wraps another item is shown."? That sentence just doesn't make any sense! I'm sure that what you're trying to do is easily solved, but you're going to have to try to explain it better.

Comment: Have you considered binding width using a converter? The converter could encapsulate your calculation logic. Might have to be a multibinding. I also don't quite follow what your logic is.

Comment: No, I haven't considered it yet because my code is pretty slow and I'm looking for a replacement for it. It would be great if it were virtualizable, since a UniformGrid doesn't support virtualizing

Comment: I noticed this question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/407291/how-to-correctly-implement-virtualizingwrappanel-i

Comment: If you want to use the functionality of a wrap panel then just use a wrap panel and modify its' behaviour in a custom control. Don't try to re-make it from scratch!